# Matrix cipher - symmetric or asymmetric cryptosystem?

Tags: encryption, symmetric, decryption, matrix-multiplication

Matrix cipher is defined by:

a) Encryption: $C = K \times Z$, where $C$ is a cryptogram vector, $Z$ is a message vector and $K$ is encryption matrix (encryption key)

b) Decryption: $Z = K^{-1} \times C$, where $K^{-1}$ is decryption matrix (decryption key), which is inverse to matrix $K$.

Is the matrix cipher symmetric or asymmetric cryptosystem?

Comment: Given $K$, how difficult is it to compute $K^{-1}$ (and hence $K^{-1} \times C$)?

Comment: For an asymmetric cryptosystem, you need two different keys that should not be computable from each other.

Comment: The calculation of the inverse matrix has a polynomial complexity - it is relatively fast even for very large matrices. So when I take this into account, we are talking about an symmetric cryptosystem? Thank you for reassurance.

Comment: See Hill Cipher.